# how to convert array of object to comma separated array of object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have array of object and I want to convert this to comma separated object.

```
let arr = [{name:"k"},{name:"p"}];
  console.log(...arr.join(','));
```

I'm getting this `[ o b j e c t   O b j e c t ] , [ o b j e c t   O b j e c t ]`
I want to in this format `{name:"k"},{name:"p"}`.

Comment: If you were happy for the output to be just *similar* to what you asked for, rather than precisely what you asked for, you should have said that in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not! just turn it to *JSON* format, then remove *open or closed square-brackets*:

```
let arr = [{name:"k"},{name:"p"}];
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr).replace(/\[|\]/g,''))
```

*Result as expected:* `{"name":"k"},{"name":"p"}`

Comment: *"Result as expected:"* It isn't, though. The OP asked for `{name:"k"},{name:"p"}`, this gives them `{"name":"k"},{"name":"p"}`. Apparently being just *similar* is good enough for them, though. :-) Would have been good if they'd said that in the question. :-|

Answer (score 2):

The default conversion of plain objects to strings results in `"[object Object]"`. (More about why you got the specific output you got below.) If you want something different, you have to do that with your own code.

For instance, you could use `map` to convert the objects to strings, then use `join` on the result:

```
const result = arr.map(({name}) => `{name: ${JSON.stringify(name)}`).join(",");
```

Live Example:

```js
let arr = [{name:"k"},{name:"p"}];
const result = arr.map(({name}) => `{name: ${JSON.stringify(name)}}`).join(",");
console.log(result);
```

That just does the one specific property of course. If you want to include others, you'll need a loop/mapping operation in the `map` callback (perhaps starting with [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) on the object).

```
const result = arr.map(obj => {
    const props = Object.entries(obj).map(([name, value]) => `${name}: ${JSON.stringify(value)}`);
    return `{${props}}`;
}).join(",");
```

Live Example:

```js
let arr = [{name:"k"},{name:"p"}];
const result = arr.map(obj => {
    const props = Object.entries(obj).map(([name, value]) => `${name}: ${JSON.stringify(value)}`);
    return `{${props}}`;
}).join(",");
console.log(result);
```

If you don't mind quotes around the property names, then as [shobe said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70273076/157247) you can do that by applying `JSON.stringify` to the entire object.

```
const result = arr.map(obj => JSON.stringify(obj)).join(",");
```

But your question didn't show quotes around property names.

Live Example:

```js
let arr = [{name:"k"},{name:"p"}];
const result = arr.map(obj => JSON.stringify(obj)).join(",");
console.log(result);
```

---

Why you got the specific result you got:

I was initially surprised by the output you got, but it does make sense after a moment's thought: Your code does `console.log(...arr.join(","))`, which does this:

- Calls `join` on `arr`, which combines its entries together into a string using their default convert-to-string behavior, with a single comma in-between.
- Spreads out that string into discrete arguments to `console.log` as though you'd written `console.log("[", "o", "j"` etc.

Comment: thanks T.J. Crowder.

Comment: good approaches, but why do you loop over each obj in array turn it to JSON then join them back, instead of just returning the whole array into JSON then removing brackets by replacing them with empty strings?

Comment: @TAHERElMehdi - You mean the third snippet that produces JSON? It just seemed cleaner. There would be a loop inside `JSON.stringify` anyway. :-)